# Makeファイルのコマンド行で "<( )" によるプロセス置換を使いたい

Tags: makefile

以下のようなコマンドをMakeファイルで使用したいと思います。
括弧をどのようにエスケープすれば良いですか？

```
target: a.txt b.txt
    diff <(head a.txt) <(head b.txt) > target
```

Comment: process substitution は bash の機能ですので、Makefile の先頭に `SHELL=/bin/bash` とでも書いておくと良いかもしれません。また、`head a.txt` と `head b.txt` の内容に違いがある場合には diff コマンドの exit status が 1 となりますので、エラーが発生したと判断されてしまいます（`recipe for target 'target' failed` などと表示されるかと思います）。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@metropolis さんも書かれていますが、`<()` がうまく動いていないのは make から起動されるシェルが `/bin/sh` になっていて、 bash の機能であるプロセス置換を認識できないからです。また、 diff は差分を検出すると、異常終了する仕組みになっているので、そのまま recipe に記載すると、 diff があった時点で make が abort してしまいます。

```
SHELL = /bin/bash    

target: a.txt b.txt
    diff <(head a.txt) <(head b.txt) > target || :
```

ですで、上記のようにすると、期待する動作になると思います。

1. shell に `/bin/bash` を明示的に指定
2. diff の実行結果を、何もしないコマンド(`:`) でもって捨て去る。